# How to redirect a user to a new website in MVC ? Redirect appends return url to a controller method

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api, .net-4.5

I want the user to be redirected to a particular URL. In my case, `www.madhu.co.in`.

My controller action looks like this:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Redirec()
{
   return Redirect("www.madhu.co.in");
}
```

I'm calling this via a `httpPost` call.

The caller website is `http://localhost/home`.

After this method is invoked, MVC tries to redirect to `http://localhost/home/www.madhu.co.in`.

It is very weird.

**Why does MVC append my external URL to the base url ?**

However, when I re-define the method to contain a `http://`, MVC redirects to `http://www.madhu.co.in`.

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Redirec()
    {
       return Redirect("http://www.madhu.co.in");
    }
```

Why is this discrepancy ? Should I always prefix a url with `http://` to redirect to a new page ? If not, it will redirect to a `action method` within controller?

Plainly confused. Any insights ?

Comment: Yes. You should have `http://` or `https://`

Comment: If not, it should throw an error, right ? Why does it appends the `external url` to my base url ?

Comment: because its not an absolute url.

Comment: @DanielA.White: Ok, now I get it.. Relative url's will always be matched with any controller actions... thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Any URL that doesn't have a protocol (`http://`) or a forward slash (`/`) is considered a relative URL. It doesn't matter if it starts with `www`, that's just considered an arbitrary subdomain.

Since it's considered relative, it gets appended to the beginning of the end of your existing URL. So in order to redirect off site, you need a fully qualified absolute URL.

Comment: Thank you. Now, it makes sense.